# Wordpress dynamic page tree menu in sidebar

Tags: wordpress, menu, sidebar

I'm trying to generate a page tree submenu list based on the currently active top page level. The comlete page tree is as follows:

1.0.0 top page item

- 1.1.0 child page item

  - 1.1.1 grandchild page item
  - 1.1.2 grandchild page item
- 1.2.0 child page item

  - 1.2.1 grandchild page item
  - 1.2.2 grandchild page item
- 1.3.0 child page item

  - 1.3.1 grandchild page item
  - 1.3.2 grandchild page item

2.0.0 top page item

3.0.0 top page item

(Second and third top page items have similar hierarchy)

I want the page tree in my sidebar.php with the following behaviour:

- Only the currently active top page with all its children and all
  their grandchildren expanded when navigating this spesific top page
  branch
- Current page item and current parent highlighted.
- Other top page items are hidden

I short this means that the whole sidebar menu changes when moving between top pages but remains unchanged within the branch/navigation of a each top page down to single page.

Furthermore I'm like to display the page items by menu order.

Does anyone have a code snippet og thoughts on how to achieve this?

Comment: never forget to add some code snippets in questions like this, it helps users like me understand the problem, and how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I managed to solve it. Initially I couldn't figure out where the current page item class had gone. It worked at single page level but not at parent or ancestor level. I had to insert the following right before the sidebar inclusion in the template:
`<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>`
This flushed out that bug.

Secondly i chose to hide all page items with css display:none; and only show page items with the class current_page_item, current_page_parent and current_page_ancestor with display:block;.

Last but not least here's the code for getting the page list located in my sidebar:
`<?php wp_list_pages('sort_column=menu_order'); ?>`

That's it and that's that!

Works perfectly!

However, I'm no php guru so if anyone can present me with a more graceful approach I' all ears!